# Update content of a xml in Postgres 9.2

Tags: postgresql-9.2

The following is the issue I am facing . Please help me. I am new to PostgreSQL 9.2.
How to update XML content(Any alternate for oracle's UPDATEXML).

Suppose we have the following form :-

```
<root>
<node1>abc</node1>
<node2>def</node2>
</root>
```

and we need the following form out of it:-

```
 <root>
 <node1>abc</node1> 
 <node2>def</node2>
 <node3>new node</node3>
 </root>
```